# i am trying to make an ajax request from my phonegap app to servlet running on my laptop,

Tags: ajax, servlets, cordova

i am trying to make an ajax request from my phonegap app to servlet running on my laptop,
 its hitting server but the ajax request is always going  to error part. 
If i will do the same request in normal browser working fine.

```
function cred() { 
    var username = "hisari";
    var password = "kumar";
    var ul = "ip" ;     

    $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET",
        url: ul,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg, textstatus) {
            alert("success"); 
            if (msg.id != null)
            {
            } else if (msg.error_id) 
            {       
                 //Error    
                alert('Error logging in:' + msg.error_message);
            }           
        },      
        error: function(error) {            
            alert("Error connecting to the servers" + error.message);       
        }   
    }); 
}
```

please give me a solution ,If possible suggest what can i use instead of servelet for login validation

Comment: This really isn't enough information for us to help you with. What are the contents of the error object? Have you tried `console.log` on anything?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using 127.0.0.1 or localhost for your IP? If so, you will need to use the actual IP of your machine when testing the app. This is because when you load the app into a device or simulator, 127.0.0.1 will resolve to the actual device or emulator itself, not your machine. (If using Android emulator, you can use 10.0.2.2 to get to your localhost on the machine, see http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking).

Comment: no i have provided the actual ip.... 192.168.1.5 and its hitting the servlet... but still always print the error part. I tried setting content type as json in response but no progress. still same issue...

Comment: Can you print the full JSON packet that your servlet is giving back to you?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your host to whitelist in config.xml?

`<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*" />
<access origin="http://*.google.com" />`

Comment: i have given access origin as <access origin="http://*" /> and the actual ip as 192.168.1.5. It is reaching the servlet, i checked the logs.....