# Phonegap Android - Ajax Request not working in mac OS Laptop but woking in ubuntu and other OS

Tags: android, ajax, macos, cordova

I have been making a simple ajax request to fetch xml data from Webserver and it is working fine in ubuntu eclipse and it is also working fine in my mac os laptop previously but for the past one week my ajax request is not working in my Mac os laptop but previously the same code has been working fine.And when i copy the same code in ubuntu os eclipse and there it works fine.

Below is my code

```
        $.ajax({  
            url:url,  
            dataType:"xml",  
            contentType:'application/xml',  
            timeout:10000,  
            type:'POST',  
            success:function(data) {  

                var $xml = $(data);
                var email = $xml.find('email').text();
                alert(email);

            },  
            error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown) {     
              alert("Error status :"+textStatus);  
              alert("Error type :"+errorThrown);  
              alert("Error message :"+XMLHttpRequest.responseXML);  
            }});
```

If i give the timeout value as 10000 i am getting timeout error but i am not getting any error in ubuntu.Then i increased the timeout value in my mac os now i am getting 3 alerts as i have set them in my error loop

```
First alert  :  error
second alert :  ''
third alert  :  undefined
```

can someone help me to figure out what issue i am having in my mac os

**In my log cat i am not receiving any errors....**

Previously some one has asked question similar to mine but there is no proper answer.

[i am trying to make an ajax request from my phonegap app to servlet running on my laptop,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17214832/i-am-trying-to-make-an-ajax-request-from-my-phonegap-app-to-servlet-running-on-m)